# Batch or VBscript to copy only folder structure between servers.

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

Example:

**Source:**
Server 1:

> C:\Folder1\Test2
>
> C:\Folder2\Test3
>
> C:\Folder3\Test1

**Destination:**
Server 2:
(Same structure above should be copied here with folder permissions)

**Note**: In script, have to call the above folder structure(Server 1) in separate file (Ex: Input.txt)

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I have used command **xcopy /t /e /o "source" "destination"** for coping folder structure from one location to another location in same server. Here i need to copy the folder structure to another server with same permission assigned to folders

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using RoboCopy?

*Robocopy "From Location" "To Location" /e /xf **

The switch /e drills down through every subfolder.
The switch /xf excludes any files.